# Jquery autosize font-size

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I'm using [this plugin](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/) for auto-resizing text boxes.  It works well until i try to add font-size in my css. In the .js file i see something called typography styles but am not sure how to set them.

jquery.autosize.js:

```
typographyStyles = [
    'fontFamily',
    'fontSize',
    'fontWeight',
    'fontStyle',
    'letterSpacing',
    'textTransform',
    'wordSpacing',
    'textIndent'
],
```

my coffee.js file looks like this:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("textarea").autosize()
```

The input text for this form is the text i'm trying to change:

```
<%= f.input :title, as: :text, input_html: { :class => "create" }, label: false,placeholder: "Title" %>
```

css .create:

```
.create {

border: 0px solid white !important;
resize: none;
padding: 0px !important;
margin: 0px !important;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
width: 100% !important;
}
```

font-size works but then the text box resize doesn't.

Comment: Can you add the CSS your editing and the view file with the text your trying to change?

Comment: I'm assuming you have tried font-size: and line-height: ? Do you get a console error for the js? What does the browser show it is using for font-size when you inspect the element?

Comment: font-size works but then the auto-resize text box doesn't.